# How Do You Create A Resource For A Local Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, resources

In my WPF UserControl, I've got a property defined as such:

```
    private Converters.CurrencyConverter _CurConverter = null;
    public Converters.CurrencyConverter CurConverter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_CurConverter == null)
                _CurConverter = new Converters.CurrencyConverter(decPlaces);

            return _CurConverter;
        }
    }
```

I want to set a resource to it in my xaml, but I'm not sure how to do it.  I've tried this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type LocalConverters:CurrencyConverter}"  ObjectInstance="{CurConverter}" x:Key="LocalCurConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But that's obviously not right and it gives issues with how ObjectInstance is used.  I've also tried to instead just create the object in the resource declaration as such:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <LocalConverters:CurrencyConverter x:Key="CurConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But that doesn't work because I don't have a parameterless constructor.  Forgetting about the fact that this is a converter, how can I create a resource to a property in the code behind?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the second method, added a parameterless constructor, and then set the parameters the original constructor accepted in the code-behind.